# How to exclude action activities from the UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am using a `UIActivityViewController` to share a invitation text to my app. I am trying to exclude all activities with the action category besides Notes App. I am unable to exclude "Save to Files" option.

1. Is there any way to exclude the view with action activities directly?
2. How can i exclude "Save to Files" activity option?

   ```
   @IBAction func inviteAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   let inviteText = "..."
   let actCont = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [inviteText], applicationActivities: [])
   //Exclude action activities types from the list
   actCont.excludedActivityTypes = [ .print, .assignToContact, .saveToCameraRoll, .copyToPasteboard,
                                     .addToReadingList,
                                     UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
                                     UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.CloudDocsUI.AddToiCloudDrive")]
   self.present(actCont, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540372/uiactivityviewcontroller-unable-to-exclude-save-to-files-in-excludedactivity?s=1|124.1458

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I think there is no way to exclude the " Save To Files" UIActivityType. Apple may do something for this in mere future